# I want to install nuxt js but this error is showing every time

Tags: nuxt.js

npm init nuxt-app new-project-nuxt

sh: 1: create-nuxt-app: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /var/www/html
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-nuxt-app "new-project-nuxt"

Comment: Did you tried doing steps from  [https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/441](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/441)

Comment: The way to go is indeed to use `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`. Also, more details as of your system, configuration, node version etc would be welcome. You need to know that for a Nuxt2 app, Node v16 is still the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Here's how it worked: npm init nuxt-app@latest <my-project>

Comment: Try `npx` instead rather.

Comment: I mean, do you need Nuxt3 or Nuxt2?

Comment: Nuxt2; 
Already working, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it worked:

```
npm init nuxt-app@latest <my-project>
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer when you can.